# If the destination can not be pinged, how can I get the network latency?

Tags: linux, networking, ping, latency

As I know, ping can get network latency. But if the destination has blocked ping, how can I get the network latency with a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas.

1) Specify the hopcount for ping. Traceroute uses this to trace the routers between you and the target. Start with a small hopcount, send a ping, and increment the hopcount by one every time you get an answer. Eventually, you won't get an answer since the ping goes to the target server which has ICMP blocked. At this point, your previous successful ping gives you the latency to the closest router that you were able to ping. That's not the accurate latency but could give you an idea.

2) Use another protocol instead of ICMP (Ping). E.g., if the server hosts any TCP service (such as HTTP server), you could send TCP packets to the server to get an idea of the latency.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a Windows box, use http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/jj729731.aspx

Download the zip, unpack. From CMD prompt cd to unpacked folder, then run with -t flag like this:

```
psping.exe -t www.anywebsite.com:80
```

[image: psping to remote host with open TCP port]

Please note: this assumes you have a web site running on remote host (port 80 in example above)